# Virtual folders remain after uninstall

Tags: installation, virtual, uninstallation

We use installed shield 2010 Express to make our installers.  After we use their built in uninstaller to uninstall our app everything seems removed when you go an explore the directory, but when we re-install to the same location some of our hidden reigstration files still remain (I.E. if we re-install to the same location it does not prompt for registration).  I noticed that if you navigate to the location where the uninstalled app used to be you will be able to see the uninstalled apps directory and all its contents.  This leads me to believe that after the uninstall some sort of virtual folder still remains.  Does this sound correct?  What can be done about this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This looks very weird. Uninstall usually removes every file it installed.

Some registry entries may be left, if it's unintentional, then you have to change attributes on them.

Running uninstall with verbose log `msiexec /x product.msi /l*v log.txt` could shed some light on the reason why files are not removed. You can use product GUID as parameter to `/x` option instead of .msi package.